# Align right one mat-header-cell in a angular material table with sort headers

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to align one of the headers in my table right. I tried:

```
.header-align-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
```

In a class and add it to the `mat-header-cell`. This aligned the text right but also added weird spacings to the element that made it not aligned with the rest of the headers. Tried it also without the `display:flex` but that did nothing.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Number">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="header-align-right">Number</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" align="right">{{row.Number}}</td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
</ng-conIainer>
```

As you see i align right the content of the cell and I would like to align the header as well.

Comment: Please post your HTML & CSS and what you tried so far using a code snippet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1vwuva)

```
.header-align-right{
  display: flex;
  padding: 21px 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: I now did it like this `.text-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 5ex 0 5ex 0;
  }`
but basically the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if there were two columns to be right aligned , above answer fails. can you tell how to fix that ?

Comment: This doesn't work if the text overflows into two rows of text. The text is centered by default because it is within the `button` element, and this solution does not align the `button` element, only the `th` element.

Answer (score 46):

Cell alignment is done by default via flexbox when using `<mat-header-cell>` and `<mat-cell>`, but **not** when using `<th mat-header-cell>` and `<td mat-cell>`. When using the table elements, the alignment is done with `text-align`. If you force flexbox all of the time, the table cells using `th` and `td` have the possibility of losing vertical alignment with the rest of the table.

I found that a combination of setting `text-align: right` and setting `justify-content: flex-end` works best. That way, elements with `display:table-cell` use `text-align`, and elements with `display:flex` use `justify-content`.

For your example:

```css
.header-align-right {
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

To get the arrow to show up before the header, you should use the [`arrowPosition`](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#MatSortHeader) attribute.

Also, I would suggest using the auto-added column class (`.mat-column-` + case-sensitive value of `matColumnDef`) instead of adding `class="header-align-right"`. That will align the headers, cells, and footers. So here's what I would suggest:

```css
.mat-column-Number {
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="Number">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header arrowPosition="before">Number</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Number}}</td>
  <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
</ng-conIainer>
```

Comment: This is a much better approach.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if you need to align the text within the button. When the button text overflows into two rows of text, it is center aligned by default, and there is no way to align that because it is added via the material library and is not referenced in the html. So this does not work for that use case. This only works when your table cell text does not overflow into multiple rows.

Comment: perfect, works like a charm for me. it should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

please copy paste this code in your css

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container { 
    display: flex;  
    justify-content: center; 
}

th.mat-header-cell, td.mat-cell { 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

The solutions look a bit shakey when it comes to resizing tables. the columns receive a `.mat-column-<your row name> and .cdk-column-<your row name>` class when adding the mat-cell or mat-header-cell directive.

From there, you can just do:

```
.mat-column-<columnName>, .cdk-column-<columnName> {
  text-align: right;
}
```

And similar such selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I used below style to right align data in the column:

```
.right-align-number-column {
    text-align: right;
    justify-content: flex-end;
 }
```

To right align the headers:
Removed mat-sort-header since it was not a requirement
and added text-end class conditionally for columns having numbers

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef 
**[ngClass]="{'text-end': config.customClass === 'Number'}"**>
{{ config.column | translate}}
</th>
```